# Extract files and directories separately using System.Directory

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I am familiar with monads, but not proficient. I am getting the contents of a directory and returning them. Now, I need to separate the files which are directories from the ones which are not.

`System.Directory` has a function called

```
doesFileExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool
```

I have already created a function which returns the contents of a directory. Here's the type signature:

```
getListOfFiles :: FilePath -> IO (Either IOException [FilePath])
```

Now, I want to create a function which will return a pair. The first element of the pair should contain only the filepaths which are not directories; the second should contain only those filepaths which are directories.

To summarize, given the functions:

```
doesFileExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool
getListOfFiles :: FilePath -> IO (Either IOException [FilePath])
```

how can I obtain a function:

```
getFilesAndDirs :: (FilePath -> IO (Either IOException [FilePath]),  FilePath -> IO (Either IOException [FilePath]))
```

The first element of the pair should contain only the files which are not directories; the second should contain only those which are directories. The function `doesFileExist` helps in determining if a file is a directory or not.

Since I am new to Haskell, I have found it very hard to formulate the code for this. I have tried many things but I run into type errors.

Comment: "I tried many things but I run into type errors." - Like what? Instead of asking Stack Overflow to write a whole function for you from scratch, show some things you have tried and what errors you encountered while trying them.

Comment: @amalloy, I understand the problem but do not know how I can fix it - I am a newbie to Haskell. Here is what I figured: If I have data of `[FilePath]` I can use the function `doesFileExist::FilePath->IO Bool` and get `[IO Bool]` in output. But, my data is not `[FilePath]`. Its `IO [FilePath]`.  As far as I see, my data is enclosed in a monad which is inside a monad(IO monad wraps the List monad in my case). I think I need some way to apply a function on that data.

Comment: If you want to differentiate filepaths to files from filepaths to directories, I recommend that you take a look at the `path-io` package, in your case particularly the [`listDir`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-io-1.2.2/docs/Path-IO.html#v:listDir) function.

Answer (score 0):

The first component of such pair should be something like

```
getOnlyFiles :: FilePath -> IO (Either IOException [FilePath])
getOnlyFiles fp = do
   efs <- getListOfFiles fp
   case efs of
      Left err -> return (Left err)
      Right fs -> Rigth <$> filterM doesFileExist fs
```

The second component is the same, except you want `fmap not . doesFileExist` instead of `doesFileExist`.

However, note that using such pair would require to scan the directory twice. A better design, IMO, would be using a function returning a (wrapped) pair such as

```
getFilesAndDirs :: FilePath -> IO (Either IOException ([FilePath],[FilePath]))
```

If the library provided a `partitionM` we could exploit it. Sadly it does not, but we can always define it ourselves.